# how to train a regression model on different group of rows in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, data-science

I have the following data frame :

```
id   total_transfered_amount day
 1       1000                 2
 1       2000                 3
 1       3000                 4
 2       1000                 1
 2       3000                 4
 2       5000                 3
 3       1000                 4
 3       2000                 2
 3       3000                 3
 4       1000                 1
 4       2000                 2
 4       3000                 3
```

I need to train regression model for each group of rows grouped by id
for example :

```
model_id_1=lm(day~total_transfered_amount)
model_id_2=lm(day~total_transfered_amount)
model_id_n=lm(day~total_transfered_amount)
```

how can apply lm on a group of data with the same `id`, and put it in a model ? then again for another group of rows by another `id`?

can i use `apply` family? if yes how? or  can `dplyr` help me in this situation?

Comment: @akrun I appreciate your help

Comment: @DatamineR  I appreciate your help

Comment: @mra68 I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add an alternative, I would propose going down this route:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(tidy(lm(day~ total_transfered_amount, data=.)))
```

Here, I just use `dplyr`'s grouped actions to run a linear regression by `id`. This gives you a dataframe with coefficients as output. See:

```
> df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(tidy(lm(day~ total_transfered_amount, data=.)))
Source: local data frame [8 x 6]
Groups: id [4]

     id                    term  estimate    std.error  statistic   p.value
  (dbl)                   (chr)     (dbl)        (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)
1     1             (Intercept)  1.000000 0.0000000000        Inf 0.0000000
2     1 total_transfered_amount  0.001000 0.0000000000        Inf 0.0000000
3     2             (Intercept)  1.166667 1.9720265944  0.5916080 0.6599011
4     2 total_transfered_amount  0.000500 0.0005773503  0.8660254 0.5456289
5     3             (Intercept)  4.000000 1.8708286934  2.1380899 0.2785092
6     3 total_transfered_amount -0.000500 0.0008660254 -0.5773503 0.6666667
7     4             (Intercept)  0.000000 0.0000000000        NaN       NaN
8     4 total_transfered_amount  0.001000 0.0000000000        Inf 0.0000000
```

Note that the `Inf` and `NaN`s are produced since the data that you posted have a perfect 1:1 relationship between the dependent and the explanatory variable for `id`'s 1 and 4. It is interesting to note that in contrast to the `nlme::lmList` option, you can actually see this here. You can also look at the options of `broom::tidy` to add e.g. confidence intervals etc.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for , that's right i have perfect fit in my data.

Comment: in case of real data sets is it possible to join cross validation to this solution as well?

Answer (score 3):

if you were looking to use dplyr you can do it

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), total_transfered_amount = c(1000,2000,3000,1000,3000,5000,1000,2000,3000,1000,2000,3000), day=c(2,3,4,1,4,3,4,2,3,1,2,3))
result <-df %>% group_by(id) %>% do (model = lm(.$day ~.$total_transfered_amount))
```

Comment: Looks like we both typed the answer at the same time! jinx!

Comment: Brilliant! I utilised it!

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way is to utilise lmList function from nlme package:

```
library(nlme)
models_id <- lmList(day ~ total_transfered_amount| id, df)

models_id
Call:
  Model: day ~ total_transfered_amount | id 
   Data: df 

Coefficients:
  (Intercept) total_transfered_amount
1    1.000000                   1e-03
2    1.166667                   5e-04
3    4.000000                  -5e-04
4    0.000000                   1e-03

Degrees of freedom: 12 total; 4 residual
Residual standard error: 1.020621
```

Comment: in case of real data sets is it possible to join cross validation to this solution as well?

Comment: What do you mean by cross validation? The object from lmList return as a list of 4 separate lm models, which can be extracted for separate predictions, on top of the commands implemented from the packages (e.g. summarising coef of all lm objects with `coef`, and plotting of all lm model with `plot.lmList`)

Comment: @ AdamQuek what i mean is : how can we change the code to split it to train and test sets and include the evaluation result to the output data frame.

Comment: `fit <- lmList(formula, data=train)` and then predict with `predict(fit, new.data=test, se.fit=T)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to split your data frame per id and `lapply` your regression formula,

```
list1 <- split(df, df$id)
lapply(list1, function(i)lm(i$day ~ i$total_transfered_amount))
```

For efficiency. and to get coef. and intercept, `data.table` option should be very efficient,

```
setDT(df)[, .(new = lm(day~total_transfered_amount)[1]), id]
#   id               new
#1:  1       1.000,0.001
#2:  2 1.166667,0.000500
#3:  3      4e+00,-5e-04
#4:  4       0.000,0.001
```

Comment: Is it efficient enough? because this data frame is getting larger and larger by time. on the other hand i need to store coefficient and intercept in a data frame for each id

Comment: @sanaz, you can try with `data.table`